# can't find gnuplot in /usr/local/bin

Tags: bash, software-installation, latex, gnuplot

I am running a bash script that I found which takes care of producing latex with gnuplot.

The script includes the line:

```
gnuplot_cmd="/usr/local/bin/gnuplot";
```

and

```
if [ ! -e $gnuplot_cmd ];
then
  echo "# Error: gnuplot not found";
```

The bash script throws an error in my computer. I have `gnuplot` installed and it works. However, there's no gnuplot in `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot`.

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do a `whereis gnuplot` to see where it is located & point there instead of `/usr/local/bin` (which contains only user added scripts usually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `whereis gnuplot` to find out where it's located, eg.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   whereis sudo                                                                            
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/sudo /usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz
```

then you could modify your script to point where it's located

ps:  I don't use `gnuplot` thus why I used `whereis sudo`.  The answer shows `sudo` is located in /usr/bin/ (so references to /usr/local/bin/ would be changed to point /usr/bin/ if that's the answer you get), also where it's man page is etc.

Comment: Hi guiverc, I tried your suggestion but the bash script is still complaining that it can't find gnuplot

Comment: There could be more than a single reference, though the `gnuplot_cmd="/usr/local/bin/gnuplot"` use of a variable would I hope reduce the references that need change.  Otherwise you could try a `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gnuplot /usr/bin/gnuplot`  (ie. let it have the /usr/local/bin/gnuplot but it points elsewhere, maybe even without softlink (-s))

Comment: What I'd do would likely depend on how I installed the software, was it `apt` installed? (I wouldn't expect any reference to /usr/local/bin) OR was it built from source? (tarball etc) where it would be more likely.  What I'd do would likely differ on info I currently don't have (eg. if from source I'd look more at at what I did to install...)

Comment: I used apt-get to install gnuplot.

Comment: I agree with user535733 in it's possibly a script error, https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnuplot (I don't know your release, so used my own) shows there are many options... How it was installed can change dependencies & what is executed (Qt? X11? or the noX) where you seem to be scripting for noX but do you have it installed?  (it uses a different binary!!)

Comment: Thanks guiverc! I just realized that I was editing the wrong bash script. I changed it to /usr/bin/gnuplot and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/*` is a location for non-apt software.

If you installed `gnuplot` using apt, look for it in `/usr/bin/*`

Comment: I followed guiverc's advice and my terminal says that gnuplot is in :  /usr/bin/gnuplot /usr/lib/gnuplot /usr/share/gnuplot /usr/share/man/man1/gnuplot.1.gz . I tried each one except the last and even with /usr/bin/gnuplot, it still fails.

Comment: And @user1237300 why isn't his answer marked as the accepted one?

Comment: because I haven't resolved the problem yet :(

Comment: You have the right answer. If it does not work, then it's time to troubleshoot your script. Humans make typos.